# connected udp multicast needs bind in the sender side

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have an ambiguous issue, I have a multicast group between two users one of them is a sender and another is receiver I did these scenarios in each side:

Receiver:

1. create a udp socket.
2. bind to a multicast group address
3. connect to the sender side ( connect(sender ip))
4. join the multicast group
5. recv from the multicast group.

Sender:

1. create a udp socket.
2. send to the multicast group.

In this scenario above when sender sent data receiver couldn't receive but if we checked the receiver side by tcpdump there is data was received from multicast group.
but if there is no connect to sender side in receiver, data will be received.

BUT Actually, If we let the sender bind to the multicast address before send to the multicast group and also receiver connect to the sender side as scenario above data will be received successfully!!!!
Any explanation when we added the bind in the sender side ???

Answer (score 2):

You might want to [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) the sender's socket to the multicast group to speed up sending, but don't [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) the receiver since it restricts it to unicast (yes, it's a bit confusing, but that's how it works). Just [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) the receiver to the group/port, and do the [`setsockopt(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) with [`IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/ip.7.html) to join the group.

Comment: I connect the receiver socket to get the value of PMTU using getsockopt() of IP_MTU

Comment: Does that really help you? Are you doing multicast over WAN? Just restrict your datagrams to some sane/safe size.

Comment: @Nikolai sender side `connect` sets the default address, receive side filters on the destination address, one could say a weak form of [source-specific multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-specific_multicast).

Comment: You meant *source address*, right? Yeah, that looks like how it is supposed to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: `don't connect(2) the receiver since it restricts it to unicast (yes, it's a bit confusing, but that's how it works)` Do you have a source for this or an explanation of this behavior? It seems you are right, but I couldn't find anything on this anywhere.

Comment: @HubertApplebaum , I found. Firstly, it mentioned in _connect(2)_ man page: `If the socket sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM, then addr is ... the only address from which datagrams are received.` And it is (unicast) address of host who sent datagram, not multicast address. Secondly, it mentioned in _ip(7)_ man page: `In the current implementation, connection-oriented sockets are allowed to use only unicast addresses.` I wouldn't treat SOCK_DGRAM socket as "connection-oriented", but it seems like after connect() call it becomes like this. Agree, this behavior is unwanted. Thanks to kernel devs! >:[

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'connected UDP multicast'. It is is connected or it is multicast. Remove the connect() steps completely.

Answer (score 0):

On the receiver side, both the bind() and connect() calls do the same thing: they associate a given Internet socket address with a given connectionless socket. For the `bind()` call -- in which the Internet socket address is the address of the multicast group -- this means that the socket will only receive UDP packets whose destination address is that of the multicast group. For the `connect()` call -- in which the Internet socket address is that of the sender -- this means that the socket will only receive UDP packets whose destination address is that of the sender, which isn't what you want.

The `connect()` call is overriding the `bind()` call, resulting in no packets being received.

Replace the `bind()` call with a `connect()` call *to the multicast group* and you should still receive the UDP packets -- or keep only the `bind()` call. It's your call.